# Help understanding iostat output

Tags: linux, winscp

I am `watch`ing `iostat` while doing a remote copy using WinSCP. WinSCP is reporting a ~8MB/s transfer rate.

`iostat` reports a 2.37MB/s read rate.

How does that make sense?

```
Every 13.0s: iostat -m /dev/sdb1                        Fri Apr  1 19:22:38 2011

Linux 2.6.35-27-generic (moabdemo)      04/01/2011      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           3.26    0.00   11.25   45.07    0.00   40.42

Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sdb1             66.74         2.37         0.01       3050         18
```

And every minute or so the MB/s rate has been increasing from an initial .04 to it's current level.

Comment: 3 minutes later it has climbed to 3.02MB/s

Comment: likewise, 30 minutes later it has climbed to 5.01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run once-off as you are doing it, `iostat` reports the average statistics since the system was last booted, not real-time usage. If you use the interval argument (eg. `iostat -m /dev/sdb1 5`), then only the first report will be averages since the last boot; all the subsequent reports will show averages since the previous report.

Personally, I prefer the `dstat` command for real-time system monitoring, as it gives me a much broader view of the system and in a more compact format. Try eg. `dstat -clmndst`

Comment: thanks! From the man page, it looked like subsequent runnings would show since the last call, not from system startup.